# NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed AngularJS REST

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I had the following function, which worked fine:

```
$http.get( "fruits.json" ).success( $scope.handleLoaded );
```

Now I would like to change this from a file to a url (that returns json using some sweet Laravel 4):

`$http.get( "http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits").success( $scope.handleLoaded );`

The error I get is:

```
"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits"
```

What's the problem? Is it because fruit.json was "local" and localhost is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [w3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

```
10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed

The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource 
identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header 
containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.
```

It means the for the URL: `http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits` The server is responding that the   `GET` method isn't allowed.  Is it a `POST` or `PUT`?

Comment: Well, if I use Postman to GET `http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits`, the status is 200 ok, content-type application/json, plus I get an output of the actual json data. So that means...?

Comment: Oh, this is what Chrome\Network\Headers says: `Request URL:http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed` So does that mean that AngularJS is not actually sending a GET, but an OPTIONS?

Comment: Ah, are you running you your Angular application on localhost?  This sounds like an issue with [Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: And since I'm in Chrome now, the console says `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I am running my angular from file, but my server from localhost. Do I need to run the angular from localhost, too?

Comment: Ya, this isn't an issue with AngularJS or your code, but setting up the Access-Control stuff on whatever server you are using to serve up your files.

Comment: I moved the Angular code to localhost (needed to be done anyway). Now it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: I am getting the error even though my server is responding with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 1):

The angular js version you are using would be <= 1.2.9.

If Yes, try this.

```
return $http({                
    url: 'http://localhost/fruitapp/fruits',
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/json' 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my SpringBoot project, I was getting the same error in the browser console but I saw a different error message when I looked at the back-end log, It was throwing this error: "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, message=Request method 'DELETE' not supported "  It turned out that I was missing the {id} parameter in the back-end controller:

```js
** Wrong code :** 
@RequestMapping(value="books",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Book delete(@PathVariable long id){
 Book deletedBook = bookRepository.findOne(id);
 bookRepository.delete(id);
 return deletedBook;
}

** Correct code :** 

@RequestMapping(value="books/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public Book delete(@PathVariable long id){
  Book deletedBook = bookRepository.findOne(id);
  bookRepository.delete(id);
  return deletedBook;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the server not being configured for CORS. 
Here is how I did it on Azure: [CORS enabling on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript) 
I hope something similar works with your server, too.
I also found a proposal how to configure CORS on the web.config, but no guarantee: [configure CORS in the web.config](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html). In general, there is a preflight request to your server, and if you did a cross-origin request (that is from another url than your server has), you need to allow all origins on your server (Access-Control-Allow-Origin *).

Comment: If you encountered the same problem and found a solution, could you please elaborate your solution and provide a complete answer?

Comment: Then how did you configure the server to make it work with CORS?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it helps as a search term. But I completed my answer now. I just can give you the link how to do it on Azure. I hope, you can use it in a similar way for your server. See above.