# Connecting AngularJS frontend web to my Spring MVC RESTful service

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, angular-resource

I have a Spring BOOT MVC RESTful API, which is successfully accepting GET PUT POST and DELETE requests when I test it with a REST application (like Postman for Chrome). E.g. manually I can do everything fine.

I built a Front-end website, using AngularJS. I can successfully GET the data, this is no problem.

However, when I try to PUT or POST data, I am getting a 405 Method Not Allowed. I have not implemented deletion yet but it would probably be the same.

This is my AngularJS controller.

```
$scope.updateMovie=function(){
    $scope.movie.$update(function(){
        $state.go('movies');
    });
};
```

This is my AngularJS factory

```
angular.module('movieApp.services',[]).factory('Movie',function($resource){
return $resource('http://localhost:8080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0/movie/:id',
    {
        id: '@id'
    },{
    update: {
        method: 'POST'
    }
});
```

And these are my PUT/POST methods, which as I mentioned are working correctly.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {`
    private static final MovieRepository m = new MovieRepository();

    public MovieController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(m.getAllMovies(),
            HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        Movie movie = m.getMovieById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> insert(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        m.addMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> update(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        m.updateMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> delete(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        m.deleteMovie(movie);
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

I honestly don't know what I am missing. Must be something in the AngularJS (as Java code is working when I test it manually) or some kind of configuration?

Also what is a good way to see the full POST url that is being sent?

To be clear, this is the error message:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0/movie/1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

EDIT: I also have a CORSFilter class.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post full class where your insert() and update() are defined? Also Servlet container configuration (e.g. web.xml) and full stack trace of error?

Comment: Not sure what the best way to post the full classes is. I will try to edit the post. There is no web.xml at all, I use an empty class as substitute with no configuration at all according to this guide on spring.io: http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ -- I also do not know how to get more information/stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Isn't this your case?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800709/networkerror-405-method-not-allowed-angularjs-rest

Comment: sry, no time at the moment. here's a tutorial which might help you out: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/angularjs-tutorial-getting-started-with-angularjs.html

Comment: lkmac: not my case. But looks similar. dominik: interesting tutorial. uses $http but not the factory. Getting a 400 Bad Request when I try to POST that way. ( $http.post('http://localhost:8080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0/movie',$scope.movie) )

Comment: If it works *by hand* and not from Angular.js, my advice would be to use a tool to spy the exact content of requests like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org), and simply run the same request first by hand, next through Angular.js and look the actual HTTP requests. It you do not find the reason of the error, you could at least post relevant details here.

Comment: Thanks Serge, that's exactly the kind of tool that I was looking for. :) I will investigate further and come back.

Comment: Sorry for slow response, I was busy. My POST request contains a $promise and $resolve data element. This is not accepted by my code. Not sure how to remove these? {"id":1,"title":"Test Movie 1","director":"Joachim Seminck","year":1987,"$promise":{},"$resolved":true}